# Powershell #Requires Statement when multiple versions of a module are installed

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I'm working with the [Az module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az/5.6.0).
I have the following requirements:

```
# Az modules
#Requires -Module @{ ModuleName = 'Az.Accounts'; RequiredVersion = '1.9.5' }
#Requires -Module @{ ModuleName = 'Az.ApplicationInsights'; RequiredVersion = '1.1.0' }
#Requires -Module @{ ModuleName = 'Az.Compute'; RequiredVersion = '4.5.0' }
#Requires -Module @{ ModuleName = 'Az.Functions'; RequiredVersion = '1.0.2' }
#Requires -Module @{ ModuleName = 'Az.Network'; RequiredVersion = '3.5.0' }
#Requires -Module @{ ModuleName = 'Az.Relay'; RequiredVersion = '1.0.3' }
#Requires -Module @{ ModuleName = 'Az.Resources'; RequiredVersion = '2.5.1' }
#Requires -Module @{ ModuleName = 'Az.ServiceBus'; RequiredVersion = '1.4.1' }
#Requires -Module @{ ModuleName = 'Az.Storage'; RequiredVersion = '2.7.0' }
#Requires -Module @{ ModuleName = 'Az.Websites'; RequiredVersion = '1.11.0' }
```

I have multiple versions of the Az module installed, 4.7, 4.8 and some 5.x versions.
I want my script to load and use a certain version of an Az.X module. There were some breaking changes introduced in Az 5.x.

I want to load a certain version because I don't want to run into the scenario where a version with some breaking changes is installed and my script doesn't run correctly. For that, I wanted to specify the RequiredVersion because that's what I developed/tested with.

Strangely, I run into a series of errors **sometimes** (which is really annoying).

When looking into the following errors, please bear in mind that I DO have installed the required versions mentioned in the first code section.

**Error 1**

```
. : The script '<aScript>.ps1' cannot be run because the following modules that are specified by the "#requires" statements of the script are missing: Az.Accounts.
At line:1 char:3
```

**Error 2**

```
. : The script '<aScript>.ps1' cannot be run because the following modules that are specified by the "#requires" statements of the script are missing: Az.Functions.
At line:1 char:3
```

**Error 3**

```
Import-Module : Method 'get_HomeAccountId' in type 'Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.Models.SimpleAccessToken' from assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Cmdlets.Accounts, Version=1.9.5.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Az.Accounts\1.9.4\Az.Accounts.psm1:103 char:1
```

Errors 1, 2 and 3 are happening in ascending order, i.e. I've run the script three times in a row with 3 different errors.

What could be the issue? Is it possible to have multiple modules versions installed and CHOOSE which one is used?

Comment: Does the below answer help?

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely have multiple versions of even same module.

*My assumption is that this issue is similar to [this](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8125) issue in the PowerShell engine.* Try installing the latest version of PowerShell Core and verify that the `Az.Accounts` module shows up when running `Get-Module -Name Az -ListAvailable`. Now, try running your scripts in updated version.

Comment: Upgrading to PS Core is not really a solution. I'm currently working on 5.1, upgrading would involve a lot of refactoring and I don't really do that now. Nonetheless, the Az should be compatible with PS 5.1 from what I've read in the docs.

Comment: Can you try it once? This is a known issue. You can downgrade it back anytime.

Comment: Okay, let's say it works, and then? I'm still left with this issue in 5.1 which I need to use at the moment.